# Java process when terminated abnormally with Kill or pkill unix comamnds doesnot delete temporary files

Tags: java, kill-process

When a tool developed in Java is launched, it creates temporary files in a folder. If terminated properly those files are getting deleted , but if terminated with kill or pkill commands those files are not getting deleted. Is there any way to send a signal to java process to delete those files before terminating the process? 
Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: `kill -15`? *"Termination signal. This is the default and safest way to kill process."* Have no idea if it works though...

Comment: This question suits better in [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `File.deleteOnExit()` is fragile when it comes to process termination. In contrast, using the NIO API with the `StandardOpenOption.DELETE_ON_CLOSE` seems to be more reliable even though it’s specification only says: “If the `close` method is not invoked then a *best effort* attempt is made to delete the file when the Java virtual machine terminates”

E.g. when running the following program:

```
File f1=File.createTempFile("deleteOnExit", ".tmp");
f1.deleteOnExit();
final Path f2 = Files.createTempFile("deleteOnClose", ".tmp");
FileChannel ch = FileChannel.open(f2, StandardOpenOption.DELETE_ON_CLOSE);
System.out.println(f1);
System.out.println(f2);
LockSupport.parkNanos(Long.MAX_VALUE);
// the following statement is never reached, but it’s here to avoid
// early cleanup of the channel by garbage collector
ch.close();
```

and killing the process while it hangs at `parkNanos`, the JVM leaves the `deleteOnExit` tmp file while correctly deleting the `deleteOnClose` file on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add shutdown hook and clean everything you need explicitly.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() { 
        //put your shutdown code here 
    }
});
```

This is actually the same what `java.io.File#deleteOnExit` does for you.

Comment: If it’s the same what `deleteOnExit` does, how is it supposed to solve the problem?